# What is the difference between the two forms XML?

Tags: android, xml

I want to add the second Activity and there are two formats. Are they both right?

```
 <application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

    <activity
        android:name=".SecondActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name">  

</application>

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

    <activity android:name=".SecondActivity" >

    </activity>  

</application>
```

I am not sure what kind of format is ok and how many formats does it have to add an activity.

Comment: will prefer first one as there in no `intent-filter` for second activity , so it increase code redability

Answer (score 0):

Both format is **identical** (if I except the `label`). In the first you declare a new xml node with no children so it's closed directly at the end (don't forget `/`) like this :

```
<activity
        android:name=".SecondActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name"/>
```

You could compare this with the `img` tag in html `<img src=""/>`

Comment: Thanks a lot...Now I see..one means has children,one means not.

Comment: and it's usually a shortcode, kind of, as it reduce the amount of char needed to declare a node. @vankee don't forget to mark my answer as valid